# Resize jQuery dialog content on dialogresize event

Tags: css, jquery-ui

When setting a content div's height during a jQuery dialog 'dialogresize' event, the div's height is unchanged.

See example: [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/IanQuigley/KQuEU/1/)

With

```
<div id='myDialog'>
   <p>some text</p>
   <div id='resizeToParent' style='overflow: scroll'>
        <div style="background: #ffc; width: 100px; height: 200px;"></div>
   </div>
<div>
```

I want the 'resizeToParent' div to take up 100% of the remaining available space inside the dialog. To do this; I bind a function to the [dialogresize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (and as a side-effect display the height of the div and the parent inside the innermost div) and set the div's height.

```
 $('#myDialog').bind("dialogresize", function (event, ui) {
 $('#myDialog #resizeToParent')
      .css('height', $('#myDialog').css('height') - 200);
```

However, the 'resizeToParent' div's height does not change!! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S3FQv/

**Solution**: Use `.height()` instead of `.css('height')` for reading in the parent's computed height.

Comment: Thanks. This seems so obvious to me now, because css(height) returns a string with "px" at the end. Doh!